# How do I run a C++ Program in Sublime 3 (Ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sublimetext3

So I have started to use Sublime Text 3 recently with my Ubuntu OS. I wanted to test it out so wrote a simple piece of c++ code. But when I try to build it does nothing, I have checked online and still nothing I even installed a build system (https://github.com/shikharkunal99/Sublime-Build-System) and still whenever I go to build it just opens open a black section at the bottom (see picture)

[image]

Comment: Why not run it from the terminal for the time being?

Comment: The background being black isn't normal. Perhaps there's black text on the black background. Try highlighting it.

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Is your build-system set to Automatic or did you select a specific one?

Comment: Hi thanks all for the comments. I had it set to C++ Single File and not automatic. I will try highlighting the black background also.

Answer (score 2):

Install g++ to run c++ code

```
apt-get install g++
```

Then I will tell you a personal trick that I used. it is:

```
find | grep "part of your filename"
```

Replace "part of your filename" section with the name of the file or a part of the name of the file.
Suppose, the file name is Here.c. I type "Here" in place of part of your filename.
Then the final step, type

```
./a.out
```

Output is ready in front of you.

Comment: sorry for leaving the post incomplete. The code for running it is "g++ Here.c". The find part was only to help you find the file in case you couldn't find it. (Happenned to me a couple of times)

Answer (score 2):

#### *This post will help you in setting up Sublime Text 3 in a way that leads to a good workflow specifically for C++ programming environment (Ubuntu, GNU C++ Compiler) :*

Note: Only the following step is essential for running c++ programs.

### 1. Create a Build System in Sublime Editor :

Sublime Text provides build systems to allow users to run external programs.

1. Go to `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System`.
2. `Paste` the following code in the file

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -pthread -H -std=c++17 \"${file}\" -o runfile && ./runfile <input.in> output.out"], 
//above line works fine if input.in and output.out files are present in same directory in which .cpp file is present else add complete address of these files for using them as common input output files in your system.
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir":"$file_path",
    "selector":"source.c,source.c++,source.cpp",
    "variants": [
   { 
       "name": "Variant Run",
       "cmd" : ["gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"g++ $file_name ;echo ------------Output-------------; ./a.out;echo;echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\""
     ],
   }
 ]

}
```

3. `Save` the file (By default the file is placed in "~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User" dir) something like "C++17.sublime-build" to differentiate it from the other build system files.
4. Create input.in and output.out text files in your working directory. This can be used for piping input from the input.in file, and output to the output.out file.

- Note in the first line it uses the -std=c++17 flag to enable the latest features of C++17. If you don't want this or want to use C++14, replace this with the -std=c++14 flag.
- Refer to https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++ for different compiler flags.
  See Also https://discuss.codechef.com/t/are-any-compiler-flags-set-on-the-online-judge/1866

### 2. Setup window layout :

1. Create three new c++ file, file.cpp. `Select View > Layout > Columns : 3.` This will create three columns in the workspace. `Select View > Groups > Max Columns : 2`.
2. Write a hello world program & save inputs if any in the input.in file, and test its working. Use `Shift+Ctrl+B` and `Select C++17` to build and execute the file (If selected `C++17 - Variant Run` it will execute the program in a separate terminal window like a normal program would).
   The windows will look like this when you are done.
   [Layout Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juWCJ.png)

### 3. Precompile headers :

Generally useful in competitive programming, we can speed up compilation time by precompiling all the header files as mentioned [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53909), i.e. by precompiling the bits/stdc++.h header file.

1. For this, first, navigate to the `stdc++.h` file. This will be located at a directory similar to `~/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits` Open terminal window here.
2. Run the command `sudo g++ -std=c++17 stdc++.h`, to compile the header. Take care to use the same flags you used in your build system. Check to make sure that the `stdc++.h.gch` file was created in that directory.

### 4. Sublime Text features :

Snippets & Completion
Read up on the documentation of snippets and completions at the official guide.

### 5. Other Features :

Read https://scotch.io/bar-talk/best-of-sublime-text-3-features-plugins-and-settings

Answer (score 0):

This program works perfectly fine for me using Build 3120, and I expect it will work fine with previous builds. First, you need to select **`Tools → Build System → C++ Single File`** (**`Tools → Build System → Automatic`** should also work, but I prefer to be explicit). Then, either hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> or select **`Tools → Build With…`** and select `C++ Single File - Run`. This will compile your `.cpp` file to an executable in the same directory as the source file, then run it.

[image: stuff]

Comment: If this does not work for some reason, please ensure that you have the required components of the gcc toolchain installed. Also, please open the console (`Ctrl-\``) and post any errors or tracebacks into your question.

Comment: Thanks very much MattDMo I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also got various issues with this thing finally I got an amazing thing in the package control pallet.Follow the instructions:

1.Open up the Package control Pallet

2.Search for C++ Builder

3.You will see C++ Builder-Mingyang Yang

4.click it and then wait for a couple of seconds

5.finally go to tools->build system->select C++ Builder-Mingyang Yang

6.finally tap the `Shift+Ctrl+B` and then select C++ Builder-Mingyang Yang Build and Run

7.finally here you go you can not only build this but also use the console for input

Note:This will execute only when there is gcc compiler included in the terminal otherwise at first install gcc by the command `apt-get install gcc` then you can use c++